# Apache Http sevrer + Django Application running independent

Tags: django, apache

I have setup, where i have installed three django application and i have configured to Apache Http server with Wsgi.py file.

whenever i want to make changes to one App in django then i want to restart whole Apache http server, result in it will affect the remaining two django application.

is it possible to start or stop django app from apache http server independently.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to touch wsgi.py file, mean change file timestamps:

`touch path/to/your/wsgi.py`

By this way, all django applications is separated.

Comment: i want to start or stop from http server GUI, is it possible??